# Android Nougat ignores string-resources located in res/values-zh-rTW

Tags: android, localization, android-7.0-nougat

An application supports 3 languages:

- English
- Simplified Chinese
- Traditional Chinese

Resources are located respectively in directories:

- res/values
- res/values-zh-rCN
- res/values-zh-rTW

On pre-Nougat versions all worked as it is described on the corresponding page of docs - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.

Currently on Nougat when a user switched device to any of Simplified Chinese languages resources from values-zh-rCN are used. But when user switch device language to any of Traditional Chinese application still uses values from values-zh-rCN (which looks like valid behaviour if you assume an absence of Traditional resources). Finally, if I remove directory values-zh-rCN from the project the application will completely ignore Traditional resources and use default English ones.

Have anyone encounter such problem and is there a solution other than reporting a bug to Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've reported this bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235561
For now, I've implemented this kind of workaround, maybe someone will find it useful. 
First, we need to create a BroadcastReciever that will listen for system language changes:

```
private class LanguageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean isNougatTraditionalChinese() {
    return isNougat() && Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag().contains("zh-Hant");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!application.getConfiguration().isLanguageSet()) {
            if (isNougatTraditionalChinese()) {
                String[] supportedLangTags = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_values);
                application.getConfiguration().setLanguagePreference(supportedLangTags[2]);
                application.updateLanguage();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

... within application language update looks approximately like that ...

```
private void updateLanguage(String langTag) {
    Locale myLocale = L10nUtils.createLocaleByTag(langTag);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

... and register that BroadcastReciever within context ...

```
context.registerReceiver(new LanguageChangeReceiver(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED));
```

Comment: Could you please specify the array R.array.language_values, and createLocaleByTag method. Thank you!